# php regex or preg_match colorbox (jQuery)

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, colorbox

i have an ads site where images are located and named as the follow:

```
images/139/16_2_139.jpg
```

where: -

- `images/139/` is the users folder
- `16` is the id of ad
- `2` is the number of images available for this ad
- `139` is the user id

examples

```
images/1390/3800_12_1390.jpg
images/27/728_7_27.jpg
images/8563/13281_2_8563.jpg
```

Now I need to display every images concerning this ad in a slideshow (colorbox)

i extract the ad id and the user id from sql

i need that php read in the directory every images concerning the ad id and the user id and display it in colorbox slideshow (jQuery addon)
the ad id goes from 1 to 15000 and the user id goes from 1 to 9000 and can also be more

i dont know if better regex or preg_match can solve my problem

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found myself a solution who work
i share for reference:

```
function microtime_float()
{
   list($usec, $sec) = explode(' ', microtime());

   return ((float)$usec + (float)$sec);
}
ini_set ("display_errors", "1");
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$start = microtime_float();
$b = '<br />';  $ad = 16;   $cust = 139;
$directory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/ginew/advertiser/images/'. $cust .'/';
// echo $directory;
if( is_dir( $directory ) ) {
$handler = opendir( $directory );
    $images = glob("$directory{*.jpg,*.JPG,*jpeg, *JPEG}", GLOB_BRACE);
    $cnt = count($images);
echo 'total images in directory: '. $cnt.$b;

$i=0;   $img1 = '';
while ($filename = readdir($handler)) {
    if($filename != '.' && $filename != '..') {
        $base = basename($filename, ".jpg"); // echo $base.$b;
        $ext = substr(strrchr($filename, '.'), 0); // echo $ext.$b;
        $imgsize = @filesize($directory.$filename); $imgsize =     ($imgsize/1000000) .' mb';
if ( preg_match( '#'.$ad.'_([0-9]+)_'.$cust.'#', $base, $matches ) ) { 
$i++;
 $img = $i .' matches '. $matches[0] . $ext; 
$img1.= $i .' matches '. $matches[1] .'<br>'; 

 echo $img.$b;
        } // END is_dir
          echo $i .' --> '. $filename . $ext .' => '. $imgsize .'<br />';
    } // END preg_match
} // END if filename
$end = microtime_float();
} // END while
echo '/ -------------------------- /<br>';
echo $img1.$b;
echo 'matches images found: '. $i . $b;
echo 'preg_match brauch : '.($end-$start).' Sekonnen';
```

output:
    total images in directory: 6
    1 matches 16_2_139.jpg
    2 matches 16_7_139.jpg
    3 matches 16_1_139.jpg
    / -------------------------- /
    1 matches 2
    2 matches 7
    3 matches 1

```
matches images found: 3
preg_match brauch : 0.00037693977355957 Sekonnen
```

if anybody has a better solution for this please post it
thanks to everyone
;-)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$str='images/1390/3800_12_1390.jpg

images/27/728_7_27.jpg

images/8563/13281_2_8563.jpg';

preg_match_all('#images/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)_([0-9]+)_([0-9]+)#is',$str,$res);

$r=array();unset($res[0]);
foreach($res as $k=>$v){
    foreach($v as $k2=>$v2){
        $r[$k2][$k]=$v2;
    }



}

print_r($r);
```

Comment: Hi, if i have example: 16_1_139.jpg, 16_2_139.jpg, 16_3_139.jpg, 16_6_139.jpg, 27/728_7_139.jpg, 13281_12_139.jpg, etc, i need to display only these image from ad no 16 and user no 139 from the folder: meens all images 16_XX_139.jpg in this case 4 images. thanks